# Formatting a string in java to match up perfectly

Tags: java, string, formatting

So I was wondering if anyone could help me with formatting this...

Here is what it currently looks like: 
[image: image 1]

This is what I need it to look like (without the ...): 
[image: image 2]

And here is my code for it currently:

```
    System.out.format( "%n$------------------------------------$");
    System.out.format( "%nWITHHOLDING FOR EACH EMPLOYEE%n%n" );
    System.out.format( "First Name        Last Name        Hourly Rate        Weekly Pay        Withholding Amount%n%n" );
    for( int i = 0; i < employeeNum; i++ ) {
        System.out.format( "%-10s %-10s %-10.3f %-10.3f %-10.3f%n", employeeFirstName[i], employeeLastName[i], 
                employeeHourlyPay[i], weeklyPay[i], withholdingAmt[i] );
    }
    System.out.format( "%nEND OF REPORT%n" );
    System.out.format( "$------------------------------------$");
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Why don't you increase the "10" in "%-10" until it aligns??? And omit the .3 where you don't want decimals?

Comment: You should look at libraries which can do this for you. One such is here : https://code.google.com/p/data-exporter/

Comment: Yeah I guess there isn't really a fix for this since the strings can be different sizes.  I have limited the size of the first and last name, but it will still probably not work. Thanks for confirming that with me though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have done it, just also use the aligning in the header:

```
System.out.print( "%n$------------------------------------$");
System.out.printf( "%nWITHHOLDING FOR EACH EMPLOYEE%n%n" );
System.out.printf("%-12s  %-12s  %-12s  %-12s  %-12s \n\n", "First Name", "Last Name", "Hourly Rate", "Weekly Pay", "Withholding Amount");

for( int i = 0; i < employeeNum; i++ ) {
    System.out.printf( "%-12s  %-12s  %-12.3f  %-12.3f  %-12.3f \n", employeeFirstName[i], employeeLastName[i], 
            employeeHourlyPay[i], weeklyPay[i], withholdingAmt[i] );
}
System.out.printf( "%nEND OF REPORT%n" );
System.out.print( "$------------------------------------$");
```

Here is the output:

```
...
First Name    Last Name     Hourly Rate   Weekly Pay    Withholding Amount 

Brett         Lawless       25.500        1020.000      204.000      
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this to truncate long strings:

```
static String truncto( String s, int max ){
    return s.length() > max ? s.substring(0,max) : s;
}
```

you can use this to get aligned output

```
System.out.format( "First Name        Last Name        Hourly Rate        Weekly Pay        Withholding Amount%n%n" );
System.out.format( "%-17s %-16s %-18.3f %-17.0f %-17.0f%n", 
           truncto("John-Bulwer-Lytton",17),
           truncto("Smith",16),
           123.45, 200.0, 100.0 );
```

Use your array elements in place of the literals I used for testing.

You can surely print two lines for the header.